# ¿Cómo mostrar imagen por ID desde URL en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas a todos, estoy tratando de mostrar imágenes desde una url con Javascript. Tengo varios botones con un ID, por ejemplo "1", al hacer click en el botón se pasa el ID a la función de Javascript. Esta función `abrirImagen()` debería cargar la URL de la imagen + el id del botón, por ejemplo: `http://mipagina.com/gallery.php?i=1` (siendo '1' el ID del botón).
Esta última URL completa me devuelve el source de la imagen, por ejemplo: `images/1.png`

Y necesito concatenar ese source con el URL, de la siguiente manera `http://mipagina.com/gallery/images/1.png`.

Mi código por ahora es el siguiente:
HTML

```
        <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="btn-group">
      <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="abrirImagen(this.id)">BOTÓN 1</button>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function abrirImagen(idBoton) {

$(document).on('button','#id',function(e){

    var idImg = idBoton;

    $.get( "http://mipagina.com/gallery.php", { 
        i: idImg
    })
     .done(function(resultado) {
        alert('W'+resultado); // Obtener el valor.
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

que tal ?

Tu problema es que "abrirImagen()" no devuelve nada ?

proba sacando el codigo de "$(document).on('button','#id',function(e){".

Igualmente quizas te convenga tener nombre de la imagen como propiedad en el elemento button y luego trabajar directamente con esa propiedad para no estar yendo y viniendo al server.

ej:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-image').forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('http://myurl/' + el.dataset.image);
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn-image" data-image="1.png">boton 1</button>
<button class="btn-image" data-image="2.png">boton 2</button>
<button class="btn-image" data-image="3.png">boton 3</button>
```

de esa manera en lugar de escribir el id desde el server, escribis la propiedad y te ahorras un request.

decime si te sirve eso o si no te quedo algo muy claro.

Saludos!

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder! Tiene mucha lógica lo de ahorrarse un request. Pero sí o sí necesito hacerlo de la otra manera. Capturando el resultado y concatenando.

Comment: Okey y sacando el codigo de "$(document).on('button','#id',function(e){});" devuelve algo ? porque utilizaste el evento button ? no lo habia visto nunca, estas seguro que existe ?

Comment: Probé sacando ese código y agregando la url + resultado funcionó, gracias!